# Ruby - FileUtils.cp_r cannot overwrite

Tags: ruby

I want to copy directories to another directory. (if exists, overwrite )
so In my loop,,,

```
FileUtils.cp_r(src, dst, :remove_destination => true)
```

but i met error

```
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1550:in `block in fu_each_src_dest': same file: 273 and /todpop/todpop_data/word/image/273 (ArgumentError)
from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1565:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1549:in `fu_each_src_dest'
from /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:434:in `cp_r'
from copy.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from copy.rb:15:in `each'
from copy.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
from copy.rb:8:in `each'
from copy.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

why this error occured in spite of setting :remove_destination ? T^T

Comment: Give the complete error stack

Comment: which line of code present in line# 8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to move a file `src` to the exact same location `dst`, and that returns an error by feature.

Comment: so what's the exact feature?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, he just means that `FileUtils` is designed to return an error when `src` and `dst` are the same. It is supposed to work this way. The OP should just use a guard clause to avoid executing `FileUtils.cp_r` when `src` and `dst` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some way to debug by your self. In your post I can see the line 'block in fu_each_src_dest': same file:. Now I came to the link [**`fu_each_src_dest`**](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/fu_each_src_dest). The below is the code :

```
# File lib/fileutils.rb, line 1512
  def fu_each_src_dest(src, dest)   #:nodoc:
    fu_each_src_dest0(src, dest) do |s, d|
      raise ArgumentError, "same file: #{s} and #{d}" if fu_same?(s, d)
      yield s, d, File.stat(s)
    end
  end
```

Now I believe you will get the why the error comes out.